# Laravel - File assets randomly not appearing on page load

Tags: php, laravel

I have installed laravel into a subdomain that is configured as a subdirectory of my main website.

laravel.example.com is set to point to laravel/public/ in my cpanel settings.

When I travel to the page, random elements like images, javascript, and css files do not load, and return a 404. Other times when I load the page those "missing" assets load just fine.

Why on earth would the assets load only some of the time?

Does anyone have an idea of what might be going on?

Comment: i would suggest opening up browser DevTools, and checking the Network tab for errors

Comment: Be sure to check the console tab in DevTools too, perhaps there will be a notice or error message there.  If you find anything of note, please add it here so we can help.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I just heard back from a ticket I opened with my host. I had a typo when creating the subdomain in cPanel, and I edited the record to fix it. There was some caching going on with the server and occasionally requests would try to access that non-existent folder.